# Don't have access to attribute in my controller Angular.js 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose, angularjs-ng-model

I'm building a simple form.
This form get a birthday field.
I can select a date and persist it.
But when I reload the page, I have an error

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-03-06T23:00:00.000Z` to be a date
```

I know how to resolve it. I need to convert my user.date_birthday to a Date.
So I tried this.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('TheNameApp')
 .controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, User, Auth) {

$scope.user = User.get();
$scope.errors = {};

console.log($scope.user); // display the resource
console.log($scope.user.date_birthday); //undefined

$scope.changeInformations = function(form) {
  $scope.infos_submitted = true;
  if(form.$valid) {
    Auth.changeInformations({
      gender: $scope.user.gender,
      city: $scope.user.city,
      country: $scope.user.country,
      talent: $scope.user.talent,
      date_birthday: $scope.user.date_birthday,
      user_name: $scope.user.user_name,
      email: $scope.user.email })
    .then( function() {
      $scope.infos_message = 'Done.'
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
      err = err.data;
      $scope.errors = {};

      // Update validity of form fields that match the mongoose errors
      angular.forEach(err.errors, function(error, field) {
        form[field].$setValidity('mongoose', false);
        $scope.errors[field] = error.message;
      });
    });
  }
};
```

the .html

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Birthday</label>

      <input type="date" name="date_birthday" class="form-control" ng-model="user.date_birthday"/>
    </div>
```

The user.date_birthday is not defined but I can see it in $scope.user
I need this for my next step

```
$scope.user.date_birthday = new Date($scope.user.date_birthday);
```

Why I can't see my attribute? How Can I resolve this?

Comment: Can we see an example of what $scope.user looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `User` is a resource, `.get()` is an async call. Use a callback:

```
User.get(function(user) {
    user.date_birthday = new Date(user.date_birthday);
    $scope.user = user;
});
```

Comment: it works very well ! But why I still can't accede to $scope.user.date_birthda in my controller? It's undefined. (I edit my post for more informations)